# Cannot assign value of type 'UITextField?' to type 'String?'

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

First problem:

månadsSparande is a number, like 100.

When I do this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var månadsSparande: UITextField!

@IBAction func beräkna(_ sender: UIButton) {
    totalAvkastning.text = månadsSparande
}

@IBOutlet weak var totalAvkastning: UILabel!
```

I get this error: Cannot assign value of type 'UITextField?' to type 'String?'

Second problem:

månadsSparande is a number, like 100. 
ränta is a number, like 2.

When I do this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var månadsSparande: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var ränta: UITextField!

@IBAction func beräkna(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var månad = månadsSparande + ränta
}

@IBOutlet weak var totalAvkastning: UILabel!
```

I get this error: Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to two 'UITextField?' operands

Comment: `månadsSparande` and `ränta` are not numbers like 100 or 2. They are `UITextField`.

Answer (score 0):

1- Replace: `totalAvkastning.text = månadsSparande` with: `totalAvkastning.text = månadsSparande.text`. Because you want to get the text of the text field and set it as the text of the label `totalAvkastning`.

2- Replace: `var månad = månadsSparande + ränta` with: `var månad = månadsSparande.text! + ränta.text!`.

A `UILabel` has a text property, which is the property you are interested in. Same for the `UITextField`.

If you want the text fields to be used with numbers only, then set the keyboard type property of these text fields to `Number Pad` and do the following:

```
if let månadsSparandeText = månadsSparande.text, let månadsSparandeInt = Int(månadsSparandeText), let räntaText = ränta.text, let räntaInt = Int(räntaText) {
    var månad = månadsSparandeInt + räntaInt
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I forgot to tell I want only numbers in my 2nd problem. 
månadsSparande + ränta should be a number and never a text. 
example write 100 in månadsSparande and 2 in ränta. The answer should be 100+2 = 102 
if I do what u said I get 1002